# Common variables for all subsystems in OpenMDAO

Tags: class, variables, input, openmdao, global

I'm trying build a framework which starts with reading an input file which contains some keys and corresponding values. I then update the variables accordingly:

```
from Inertia import Inertia
...  

d = hf.read_input(fin)
locals().update(d)
```

Then, I'm defining the group MDA:

```
class MDA(om.Group):

    class ObjCmp(om.ExplicitComponent):
        
        def setup(self):
            ...

        def setup_partials(self):
            ...

        def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
            ...

        def setup(self):
            ...
```

which contains two subsystems (for now):

```
self.add_subsystem('d1', SomeModule(), promotes_inputs=['x1','x2'],
                        promotes_outputs=['y1','y2'])

self.add_subsystem('obj_cmp', self.ObjCmp(), promotes_inputs=['y1'],
                        promotes_outputs=['obj'])
```

For housekeeping reasons, since the framework will eventually contain large number of subsystems, I want to keep the classes defining the particular subsystems in separate scripts, imported the the main script (the one where the Group is defined).

The problem I'm facing is that if I only read the input file once at the level of the script where the Group is defined (before entering the Group() class), the variables retrieved this way are not defined at the lower levels, for instance, I cannot use them inside SomeModule(). I'd normally define an **init**() method inside SomeModule() to be able to pass some variables:

```
def __init__(self, d):
    self.d = d
```

but since we instantiate the SomeModule() class within self.add_subsystem(), it does not work.

I would be really grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenMDAO, we deal with this instantiation timing issue in two ways:

1. We strongly discourage the use of the `__init__` method for components or groups. Instead, we recommend you rely on the `initialize` and `setup` methods. `initialize` is called inside the existing `__init__` (i.e. at instantiation time). `setup` is called much later during the build up of the model hierarchy.

We do provide a means of creating init arguments via an [options system](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.14.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/options.html#a-simple-example). Options allow for some built in validation and also give you the chance to change the values later if you want to.

2. Delaying as much as possible till `setup`, if you can. Pass your configuration file (or an object built from it if you prefer) into your component as an `option`, but don't actually use it till setup.

This goes for both components and groups. You can make the configuration data an option at all levels of your groups. They will each pass the object down to their children inside their own setup methods. This way, you only need to have the object in existence by the time you initialize the top level group. It will then pass it down to all its children.

Comment: Thank you for this response, much appreciated! I modified the code:

- initially: read the input file, save it to a dict object d, without updating locals

- at the group level: added initialize() method with declaration of 'inp_data' option, and passed the option to SomeClass() in the setup method (SomeClass(inp_data=d))

- at the component level: added initialize() method, and, in the compute() method, passed the value of the option (self.options['inp_data']) to a new variable, used from then on.

Can you confirm if this is a correct way or can this be further streamlined, please.

Comment: sounds mostly right, except that you shouldn't pass the options data down inside the `compute`. You should do it in the `setup` method instead.

Comment: Thank you @JustinGray !